# React Hooks state always a step behind

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Im having trouble resetting page = 1. In the `handleSearchClick` I have `setPage(1)` but its one click late, so after the second click page will reset to 1

> This is my current code

```
const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);
//Other states as well 

    /**
     * Handles event on search click
     */
    const handleSearchClick = async () => {
        setItems([]);
        const database = handleBaseId();
        setPage(1);
        const items = await fetchSearchPayload(page, value, option, database);
        setIsLoading(false);
        setItems(items);
    };
```

I also tried resetting page in the button itself but was getting a `react limits the number of renders to prevents an infinite loop` error message

> This is what I tried doing

```
<SearchBar
     onClickButton={handleSearchClick}
     onValueChange={handleChange}
     value={value}
     pageNum={page}
     onEnter={handleSearchOnEnter}>

   {setPage(1)}

</SearchBar>
```

I also tried using `useEffect` and added a `count` state that increments every time the `searchBar` is clicked, but I was having trouble with count itself being a step behind.

```
const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

React.useEffect(() => {
        setPage(1);
    }, [count]);

    /**
     * Handles event on search click
     */
    const handleSearchClick = async () => {
        setCount(count+1);
        setItems([]);
        const database = handleBaseId();
        setPage(1);
        const items = await fetchSearchPayload(page, value, option, database);
        setIsLoading(false);
        setItems(items);
    };
```

Any suggestions on how to reset `page` without any delays are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're attempting to set the page (async) and immediately afterwards use the `page` state in your `fetchSearchPayload` call. Considering you're hardcoding always setting the page to 1 there, you could also hardcode the 1 in your `fetchSearchPayload` call.

Another route you could go is only do the async call when the page has updated by doing something like this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const database = handleBaseId();
    const items = await fetchSearchPayload(page, value, option, database);
    setIsLoading(false);
    setItems(items);
}, [ page ]);

/**
 * Handles event on search click
 */
const handleSearchClick = async () => {
    setItems([]);
    setPage(1);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that state updates are asynchronous with hooks state updater just like `setState` in react components. The solution is to pass the page manually to function instead of depending on state

```
/**
 * Handles event on search click
 */
const handleSearchClick = async () => {
    setItems([]);
    const database = handleBaseId();
    setPage(1);
    const items = await fetchSearchPayload(1, value, option, database);
    setIsLoading(false);
    setItems(items);
};
```